# Get file list from S3 using aws service(api gateway) proxy with prefix on folder

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway, aws-java-sdk

I am using below AmazonS3Client sample code to fetch list of files from **S3** bucket with **prefix** through aws api gateway. 
But I am getting all files of that bucket.

When I check the url in the api gateway logs, the url does not have **prefix** parameter in it.

Thanks in advance

```
ListObjectsV2Request req = new ListObjectsV2Request().withBucketName("mybucket").withPrefix("myfolder").withDelimiter("/");
            req.putCustomRequestHeader("Authorization", "#####");
            ListObjectsV2Result result;
            do {
                result = s3Client.listObjectsV2(req);


                for (S3ObjectSummary objectSummary : result.getObjectSummaries()) {
                    System.out.printf(" - %s (size: %d)\n", objectSummary.getKey(), objectSummary.getSize());
                }
                // If there are more than maxKeys keys in the bucket, get a continuation token
                // and list the next objects.
                String token = result.getNextContinuationToken();
                System.out.println("Next Continuation Token: " + token);
                req.setContinuationToken(token);
            } while (result.isTruncated());
```

Comment: This code works for me, without the 'putCustomRequestHeader' call (not sure what that's there for?). That said, if you want to get back the keys / common prefixes below 'myfolder', then your prefix in this case needs to be 'myfolder/'.

Comment: I am using **'putCustomRequestHeader'**  for validating token in aws lambda...But it goes in header which is not related to url parameters(As S3 filter objects in a bucket based on url parameters eg. GET /?list-type=2&max-keys=3&prefix=E).I referred from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/v2-RESTBucketGET.html .. @redbido Have you achieved this from aws api gateway..?

Comment: I didn't expect the putCustomRequestHeader would cause an issue, just wanted to be clear I hadn't called it. No, I didn't do this from an api gateway, although as long as your auth is working (which it clearly is since you can list the bucket) I can't think of any reason why using the API gateway would change how the SDK and underlying AWS API behave in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I am able to list objects now by adding Query Strings: delimiter, prefix in api gateway configuration.[as shown in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLVug.png)